# Inline plots do not appear in Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I tried to plot inline figures in a Jupyter Notebook and in IPython, and they do not appear in the output.

Here is the snippet, followed by the output.

Cell:

```py
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(matplotlib.get_backend())

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

I've tried other backends that work; for instance the WebAgg backend does open a new browser tab with the actual plot.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: can confirm - your code works for me; but no real idea whats missing - may be some lib missing or corrupted ???

Comment: @Drako I've tried reinstalling everything from the jupyter package. I also tried using a different (empty) kernel by starting a new virtual environment, and installing it through ipykernel.

Comment: sorry - no idea - only can confirm - code works on my Python 3.8.1, IPython 7.13.0, The version of the notebook server is: 6.0.3

Comment: What's your python and jupyter notebook versions?

Comment: jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.0.0
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3

jupyterlab==2.0.1

jupyterlab-server==1.0.7
python==3.7.2